# Ошибка: Не найдена указанная процедура. При загрузке dll через jna

Tags: java, c#, dll, native, jna

У меня есть класс:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class CSharpHelloWorld
{
    public CSharpHelloWorld() {}

    public void returnHelloWorld(){}
}
```

Который я скомпилировал в dll.
Пытаюсь вызвать его через jna:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
public class JnaTest {

    public interface SharpClass extends Library {
        void returnHelloWorld();
    }
    private static SharpClass sharpClass = (SharpClass)Native.load("C:\\Users\\path_to_dll\\SharpClass", SharpClass.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        sharpClass.returnHelloWorld();
    }
}
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'returnHelloWorld': Не найдена указанная процедура.

    at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:255)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:618)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:594)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:580)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:248)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy0.returnHelloWorld(Unknown Source)
    at JnaTest.main(JnaTest.java:11)
```

Помогите понять почему не видит метода.